# node.js how to get better error messages for async tests using mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

A typical test in my node.js mocha suite looks like the following:

```
 it("; client should do something", function(done) {
    var doneFn = function(args) {
      // run a bunch of asserts on args
      client.events.removeListener(client.events.someEvent, userMuteFn);
      done();
    }

    client.events.on(someEvent, doneFn);

    client.triggerEvent();
});
```

The problem here is that if `client.triggerEvent()` doesn't do something right, or if the server breaks and never invokes `someEvent`, then `done()` will never get invoked. This leaves an ambiguous error for someone who hasn't worked with the testsuite before like:

`Error: timeout of 10500ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

My question is, is there a way to rewrite these tests, whether it's with mocha or in addition to another lib, that makes async work like this easier to follow. I'd love to be able to output something such as:

`the callback doneFn() was never invoked after clients.event.on(...) was invoked`

or perhaps something similar.

I'm not sure if using something such as promises would help this. More meaningful error messages for async/callback type code would be a great thing. If it means moving from callback/async to another workflow, I'm OK with that as well.

What are some solutions?

Comment: Could clarify what the variable `client` contains. Is it an object instance, or a module called using `child_process.fork()`, something else? How are errors managed in that side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a timeout error rather than a more precise error, **the first thing to do is to check that your code does not swallow exceptions, and that it does not swallow promise rejections.** Mocha is designed to detect these in your tests. Unless you do something unusual like running test code in your own VM or manipulate [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), Mocha will detect such failures, but if your code swallows them, there's nothing Mocha can do.

This being said, Mocha won't be able to tell you that `done` was not called because your implementation has a logic bug that causes it to fail to call the callback.

Here is what could be done with `sinon` to perform a post mortem after test failures. Let me stress that this is a *proof of concept*. If I wanted to use this on an ongoing basis, I'd develop a proper library.

```
var sinon = require("sinon");
var assert = require("assert");

// MyEmitter is just some code to test, created for the purpose of
// illustration.
var MyEmitter = require("./MyEmitter");
var emitter = new MyEmitter();

var postMortem;
beforeEach(function () {
  postMortem = {
    calledOnce: []
  };
});

afterEach(function () {
  // We perform the post mortem only if the test failed to run properly.
  if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
    postMortem.calledOnce.forEach(function (fn) {
      if (!fn.calledOnce) {
        // I'm not raising an exception here because it would cause further
        // tests to be skipped by Mocha. Raising an exception in a hook is
        // interpreted as "the test suite is broken" rather than "a test
        // failed".
        console.log("was not called once");
      }
    });
  }
});

it("client should do something", function(done) {
  var doneFn = function(args) {
    // If you change this to false Mocha will give you a useful error.  This is
    // *not* due to the use of sinon. It is wholly due to the fact that
    // `MyEmitter` does not swallow exceptions.
    assert(true);
    done();
  };

  // We create and register our spy so that we can conduct a post mortem if the
  // test fails.
  var spy = sinon.spy(doneFn);
  postMortem.calledOnce.push(spy);
  emitter.on("foo", spy);

  emitter.triggerEvent("foo");
});
```

Here is the code of `MyEmitter.js`:

```
var EventEmitter = require("events");

function MyEmitter() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

MyEmitter.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
MyEmitter.prototype.constructor = MyEmitter;

MyEmitter.prototype.triggerEvent = function (event) {
    setTimeout(this.emit.bind(this, event), 1000);
};

module.exports = MyEmitter;
```

Comment: What adds state to `this.currentTest`?

Comment: any chance you can link to that in the mocha documentation? I don't happen to see it.

Comment: I think the other problem is, `currentTest.state` never gets set to `failed` if `done()` isn't invoked

Comment: I don't know any part of the documentation that mentions it. This is a part of Mocha's documentation that is lacking. I know about it from having answered Mocha questions for years on SO and having read bug reports on github where the Mocha developers appeared fine with accessing `this.currentTest` in hooks. (For instance [this report](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1638). It would be immediately closable as "not an issue" if we're not supposed to use `this.currentTest` at all.)

Comment: And regarding your comment regarding `currentTest.state` not being set to `failed` if `done()` is not invoked, I cannot reproduce that here. If I add a  `console.log("state", this.currentTest.state);` to my `afterEach` hook and mess with the code I've shown in my answer so that `done` is not called, I get a `failed` status every time.

Comment: I'll look some more, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You should to listen to `uncaughtException` events, in addition to `someEvent`. This way you'll catch errors happening in client, and those will show up in your test report.

```
 it("; client should do something", function(done) {
    var doneFn = function(args) {
      // run a bunch of asserts on args
      client.events.removeListener(client.events.someEvent, userMuteFn);
      done();
    }

    var failedFn = function(err) {
      client.events.removeListener('uncaughtException', failedFn);
      // propagate client error
      done(err);
    }
    client.events.on(someEvent, doneFn);

    client.events.on('uncaughtException', failedFn);

    client.triggerEvent();
});
```

P.S. In case `client` is a child process, you also should listen to `exit` event, which will be triggered in case the child process dies.

Comment: Mocha i[nstalls](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/8a37e016e5629b46709891740c74d5f0b69929e0/lib/runner.js#L809) an `uncaughtException` handler globally. There's no reason to trap `uncaughtException` with special code.

Comment: @Louis as OP describes "server" and "client" components in his question, mocha may be running on one end, without access to the exceptions occuring on the other end (which is running in its own process).

Comment: I see. As far as I know the server facilities that people are likely to use by default (e.g. `express`) do not generate `uncaughtException` events that the clients can listen to. The challenge then how to instrument the server code with the safety net that will generate those events.