# Timeout error when using promises with mocha and chai when `should` expectation fails

Tags: promise, mocha.js, chai

While writing tests for a project with Mocha & Chai I noticed I could get `true.should.be.false` to fail, but when the variable under test came from a promise and that expectation failed, Mocha would time out: `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Here are the examples of things I tried (and the solution) in hopes that it'll help someone in the future.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const should = chai.should();
const assert = chai.assert;

function getFoo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({bar: true});
  });
}

describe('Example for StackOverflow', function() {

  it('will fail as expected', function() {
    true.should.be.false;
  });

  it('will also fail as expected', function() {
    var foo = {
      bar: true
    };

    foo.bar.should.be.false;
  });

  it('times out instead of fails', function(done) {
    getFoo().then(data => {
      data.bar.should.be.false;
      done();
    });
  });

  it('times out instead of fails even without arrow notation', function(done) {
    getFoo().then(function(data) {
      data.bar.should.be.false;
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should throws an error when the expectation fails, but the done() in catch() doesnt seem to matter', function(done) {
    getFoo().then(data => {
      data.bar.should.be.false;
      done();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      done();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('still throws an error in the catch() if I try to use assert.fail() inside the catch to force a failure', function(done) {
    getFoo().then(data => {
      data.bar.should.be.false;
      done();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      assert.fail(0, 1);
      done();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

For reference, here are the versions at play here:

- node: v5.12.0
- chai: v4.1.0
- mocha: v3.4.2

*This is different from [node.js how to get better error messages for async tests using mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083994/node-js-how-to-get-better-error-messages-for-async-tests-using-mocha) in that I'm specifically talking about a timeout that occurs when `should` detects a failure and throws an error that isn't caught because the promise is not returned. Their solution focuses on using `done`- mine does not need it because it's returning the promise to Mocha so that it can catch the error.*

Comment: Your problem here is exactly the same as in the other question. You are getting an uninformative error because you are swallowing an exception. Failing to return a rejected failure is one of the many ways you can swallow a exceptions. Same problem, same solution: don't swallow exceptions or rejected failures.

Comment: Your statement is correct but the other question is more focused on the `done` callback than returning a promise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **return the promise** in the test function - I wasn't doing that in my `times out instead of fails` examples, and I noticed it later while writing up my examples to ask this question.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const should = chai.should();
const assert = chai.assert;

function getFoo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({bar: true});
  });
}

describe('Example for StackOverflow', function() {

  it('needs to return the promise for the test runner to fail the test on a thrown exception - no done necessary', function() {
    return getFoo().then(data => {
      data.bar.should.be.false;
    });
  });

});
```