# Why is my sinon test timing out instead of failing?

Tags: typescript, async-await, sinon

Here is the code under test:

```
function timeout(): Promise<NodeJS.Timeout> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}

async function router(publish: Publish): Promise<void> => {
  await timeout();
  publish('requestObject');
};
```

Here is my test.  If I use the try/catch below it fails immediately with the correct error.

```
it.only('returns a valid response', (done) => {
    const publish = sinon.stub();

    publish.callsFake((publishResponse) => {
      try {
        expect(publishResponse).to.equal('wrong');
        done();
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    });

    router(publish);

    sinon.restore();
});
```

If I remove the try/catch the test times out with:

```
publish.callsFake((publishResponse) => {
  expect(publishResponse).to.equal('wrong');
  done();
});
```

> Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

I guess the promise is not resolving because the expect is failing.  And so it's not hitting the done().  Is there a way for me to rewrite this more cleanly?  Or is using try/catch the appropriate way to write this test?

I read [several SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083994/node-js-how-to-get-better-error-messages-for-async-tests-using-mocha) with a similar question and they say to ensure that the code under test is not swallowing errors.  But in my code I don't see any code swallowing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified it by awaiting the code under test instead of using the callback/done structure, and using an argument expectation (calledWith) instead of doing the expectation inside of the fake callback.

I'm not really sure why this works instead of the callback method.

```
  it.only('returns a valid response', async () => {
    const publish = sinon.stub();

    await router(publish);
    expect(publish).to.be.calledWith('wrong');

    sinon.restore();
  });
```